# Read a json file from Capistrano 3

Tags: capistrano3

I have a json file that holds some configuration settings.  I want to read that file and then set values in my recipe.  Is that possible?

Thanks

Grant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the top of your `deploy.rb`, you can use the [Ruby JSON library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html).

Something like:

```
require 'json'

my_hash = JSON.parse(File.read('filename.json'))
set :branch, my_hash["branch"]
```